# Container story for repeated work

Tags: agile, kanban-board

My QA (not only QA) is performing the same work on undefined schedule. For example: a full regression test is being done with every mobile app release. This work involves not only automation test, but manual process as well and requires a ticket.

For being able to digest this work better I want 'regression testing' stories to be grouped, right now these stories are linked to an Epic.

How you guys deal (or approach) situations where exactly the same story is being played over again?

An Epic which is always in-play?
A story stuck in one of the lanes?

Any input much appreciated!

Best,
r0cket

Answer (score 2):

Why not, instead of considering the regression testing to be a story of it own, bake it into the Definition of Done for every mobile app story?

After all, a story, on its own, should provide business value. Does an untested story provide business value? Does testing without having any actually useful features?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend differentiating between the Tests and Test Runs.

A test is the instructions on how to test feature X

A test run is the work you do in (and results of) following those instructions against version Y of the code.

You can keep the Test as a template task in your project management software and copy it for each Test Run.

This gives you both the standard set of 'stuff you need to do each release' and a history of how long it too last time, and the time before that etc.

You can also see how the Test suite grows and changes over time as features are added.